# How to overwrite a line to a text file in R?

Tags: r, file, readlines

I've read lines of a text file using readLines() . Then, I applied writeLines() to overwrite a line and write it to that file connection. Note that I want to overwrite every line of this text file. What I want is:

```
    IF X1 is Low and X2 is High THEN CLASS1
```

But what I get is:

```
    IF X1 is Low and X2 is High THEN 
    CLASS1
```

My code is as follows:

```
    con <- file("test.txt")
    a<-readLines("test.txt")
    temp<-c(a[1],"CLASS1") 
    writeLines(temp, con)
    close(con)
```

What is the problem? Is there any problem with "\n" at the end of each line which leads to this result? Is there any other method rather that readLines()?

Comment: possibly, try `writeLines(temp, con, sep = " ")`

Comment: It worked Alex. Another question is how to do it for every line of a text? It's possible for a line but when I run it for the first two lines, it only writes the second line. My first line isn't rewritten to the file.

Comment: It is written, but the second line overwrites it. You should use the `append = TRUE` option for each subsequent line.

Comment: I found the solution. It's better to use cat() and sink(). Thanks.

Comment: That is not necessarily the way to go (cat,sink).  You should take a careful look at "the law of unintended consequences"  .  To start out, how about `temp <- paste0(a[1]," CLASS1")` rather than your workaround?

Comment: `paste()` worked really better than `c()` . Thanks @Carl!